# Technique for iterating through variables and finding Instances of a specific Type

Tags: c#, reflection, iteration

i want to iterate through variables in memory in my process (loaded through a plugin dynamically), and look for instances of a specific type.

Previously i can find the specific types (or all types in memory). I can create instances of types, i could get instances that were contained as fields in a different type, but i don't know anyway just to "search" for instances of a specific type.

Comment: You can automate Windbg by parsing the output of !DumpHeap command and then cast the pointers to the managed types inside your application.

Comment: As the answers do indicate you need to attach a debugger to your application. If this is not an option you need to elaborate the problem a bit more to give you perhaps a easier solution (e.g. require the objects to register in a central collection, ...)

Comment: If attaching to process isn't an option, the windbg/sos techniques will work off a process memory dump as well. Just make sure you get the architecture right http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx

Comment: right now i'm only doing it for discovery, so i could attach a debugger, but basically i want to get a reference to them all so i can call methods on them.

Comment: This is dangerous (but possible). You need to cast a pointer to a managed object back to an object reference. But be aware that you can get random ExecutionEngineExceptions because if in the meantime a GC did run the object pointers have been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use windbg and sos.  You can !dumpheap with a -type flag.

Comment: This article, while targeted at finding leaks, demonstrates all the sos commands you'll need.  The author is using cdb.  You can use either cdb or windbg, doesn't really matter as long as you load sos.  http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/investigating-.net-memory-management-and-garbage-collection/