# Find all instances of type T

Tags: c#, reflection, types, instance

I want to get all instances of a specific type. It would be good to find them without having a list of all instances. I have only found solutions which explain how to find interface implementation. Does Reflection provide any way to achive that?

Comment: Wait, you want to find all instances of type T at a random given time in an application? IE. loop through all objects the app has and check for type T?

Comment: You need to do this from inside the application, or while debugging?  Is it a type you wrote, or one from a library?

Comment: If you already know how to find all instances that implement a specific interface, then the step to "is specific type" should be simple.

Comment: There is no *managed* way to do this without keeping your own lists. Do do this you would need to drop to SOS or similar.

Comment: Alxandr: and from where i get them? I thought AppDomain could be but i couldnt find a entry which looked helpfull. Ben: from inside the application and it is a type i wrote but actually i dont want to add something to detect it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get all instances of all loaded types that implement a given interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302542/how-do-i-get-all-instances-of-all-loaded-types-that-implement-a-given-interface)

Comment: If you go the SOS route, there's a link in here with some guidance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095448/technique-for-iterating-through-variables-and-finding-instances-of-a-specific-ty/10095550#10095550